# How to track which pages caused custom events in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, custom-events

I have multiple pages being tracked by google analytics. On all these pages I have an outbound link for which I make a call to create a custom event - the action is named the same on all the pages.

How can I see a breakdown of which pages caused this event to occur. I.e.

Page 1 - 7 clicks on outbound link, Page 2 - 2 clicks on outbound link, Page 3 - 1 clicks on outbound link, Page 4 - 19 clicks on outbound link

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All events sent to Google Analytics send with the Page they were sent from (defined by `location.pathname` and `location.search` combined, if I'm not mistakened).

You can drill down into what pages those events occurred in by clicking the secondary dimension dropdown (by default, it says "None") and select "Page".

[image]

Comment: This is great thank you. What about the other way? Say I have a page X and I want to see the CTR from that page to action? Do I have to calculate myself for all pages (i.e. clicks on action on page x divided by pageviews of page x) or is there a built in report for that?

Comment: @aloo Not by default right now, no. You could probably generate it in the Google Analytics API Query Explorer, though: http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataExplorer.html

Answer (score 3):

GA has made several changes since 2011, and so Yahel's answer is outdated.

To see all pages where an event fired, you need to go into **Events** >> **Overview** and click the event category you care about. This will take you into **Top Events**, where you can select secondary dimension **Page** to see top pages where your event category is firing.

You can drill down further by selecting Primary Dimension: **Event Action** and secondary dimension **Page**.